Why do I get this error from my ASP.NET Core Web API when I attempt to fetch API endpoint?
Background
I've been writing & running ASP.NET Core Web APIs for a long while now but suddenly when I attempt to retrieve a simple endpoint using fetch (more below) I get the following error:

VM22:1  Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:5116/Weatherforecast' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
"default-src 'none'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I've never seen this in the past.
Steps To Reproduce
You can generate a very basic ASP.NET Core 8 Web API by doing the following:
$ dotnet core new webapi -o testApi

That will include an endpoint that provides weather data.
You can do a GET on it from the web browser like:
http://localhost:5116/weatherforecast
You'll see something like:

Open Up Console / Terminal
However, if you open up a browser console (F12 in most browsers) and attempt the following command, then you will get the error I'm now seeing:
   fetch ("http://localhost:5116/Weatherforecast")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));

What I've Tried
I asked Copilot and it told me to add the following code to my Program.cs file:
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self';");
    await next();
});

This doesn't resolve the error though.
Added CORS Default
I also added the following code:
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader();
}));

app.UseCors();

CURL Works
Also, note that CURL does work to retrieve from the URL:
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:5116/weatherforecast' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'

What Will Resolve This?
What do I set in my Web API so I can make these fetch calls again?

Oh, wow, I found the definitive answer and it is a bit painful.
Here's a snapshot of the error occurring in my browser (MS Edge running on Ubuntu 24.04.1)

Take note of the URL:  localhost:5095/weatherforecast
Now, let's try the fetch command, but first let's load localhost:5095 (no weatherforecast in the url in the main browser window.

Now the fetch command works with no problem.  Oy!
In the past, it was the opposite - you had to run fetch commands on the console after loading a successful URL in your browser.
Initial URL Determines Success Or Not
So, this is all due to the initial URL where you attempt to run your fetch commands.
